# Should I retrieve records from a database in the onResume() call?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The home page of my app displays a list of records. Another page allows adding a new record. After creating a new record, on hitting the save button, when the app goes back to the home page, I want the latest record to also be displayed.

Is there a better way of retrieving all the records rather than fetching them all from the SQLite database in a call inside onResume()?

Comment: There is always the possibility of creating ever more efficient code, you have to ask yourself, is it worth it ?

Comment: i would suggest to use Room db and live data, so it will be notified automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the created model in a background job/thread and then call `finish()` only after the save is done. You can also display a loader in the meantime.

After that, in your home Activity/Fragment (?), do another background job (in order to not freeze the UI) to retrieve the data from the SQLite. When the job is done, display it. Again, you can always display a loader while the task is running.

Simple way : have a look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)